# MS Project: Task not adjusting to predecessor dates (auto-scheduled, 0% progress, tried unlinking/relinking etc)

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, constraints

I'm trying to link 2 tasks in Project and having issues with autoschedule. I set the first task to manual and put in the dates. However, when I set the second task to autoschedule and link it to the first task, the date is almost a month later than the end of the first task.

I cannot figure out why this is - only 1 predecessor, constraint type is 'as soon as possible', no 'actual' start or finish dates, and both tasks are at 0% progress. Also, the date for the second task won't go earlier than what autoschedule sets it to, no matter what I do to the constraint type or even if I unlink it and manually type in the start date I want (the line will go back to 'start no earlier than' and then the later date).

Any idea what the cause of this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

1. **The calendar that the task is using** (you can see what this is by looking at the *Task Calendar* field) If it's set to "None" then the task is following the Project's calendar.
2. **Dependencies on summary tasks.** If you have any dependencies on the summary task that the auto scheduled task you referred to is underneath, the task won't be able to start until the dependencies tied to the summary task allow it to.
3. **Resource assignments** If you have resources assigned to the task, check what calendar the resources are using. Makes sure it's the same as the calendar being used by the task.